# Remove links from image through regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove the links surrounding the images on a website. I exported the SQL file to notepad++. And using search and replace I tried to remove this links (regex). The images itself would I like to preserve.

In notepad ++ I use the following code (see [example](https://regex101.com/r/ke3ip3/2))

```
(<a href=.*?)<img.*?>(.*?a>)
```

This code works in 99% of the cases but not on pages with both a link and an image plus a link. In this case, it will select the text starting from the first link till the image itself. See also https://regex101.com/r/ke3ip3/2

Does somebody have a solution for this?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please provide some expected inputs/outputs so we know exactly what you want to happen. It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do without this.

Comment: Hi James, i've rewritten the question and added some more info :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, actually three:

There is an extra whitespace between the start of the tag and the a and therefore the first pattern matches too much:

Try it like this:

```
(<\s*a\s+href=[^>]+>)<img[^>]+>(<\/a>)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tzneTV/1)

I would also suggest having a fixed end tag pattern.

Finally, it looks like a one-off job. However, it's not recommended to parse/manipulate HTML with regex.

As discussed in the comments, a capture group around the image helps to reinsert it on the replacement. Putting it all together

```
<\s*a\s+href=[^>]+>(<img[^>]+>)<\/a>
```

Replace with in regex mode: `$1`

Comment: Would it be better if the img tag was in its own capturing group? So you can replace the match with `$1` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with that. However, the question is not clear about that and thus focused on the regex in question.

Comment: @SteveEdson You really saved my day :) Works flawless ! Had googled and  tried a lot to make it work. But regex is not the easiest thing to learn. And yes is it a one-off job. A old 'messy' website that needs a proper cleanup. But its impossible to do that by hand (1600+ pages). Thank you very much :)

Comment: @wp78de  i've put the img tag in a sepate group  (<\s*a\s+href=[^>]+>)(<img[^>]+>)(<\/a>) Thanks :)

Comment: @PeterPoortinga please upvote/accept if the answer helped you solve the problem.